# AWS CloudFormation template with Kinesis Event Consumer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to create a Lambda which is invoked when there are records in a Kinesis Stream. For this, in the template.yaml for the lambda, I have added a Kinesis Consumer in the following way -

```
  EventStreamConsumer:
    Type: AWS::Kinesis::StreamConsumer
    Properties:
      StreamARN: !Sub arn:aws:kinesis:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:stream/${EventsKinesisStream}
      ConsumerName: !Ref KinesisConsumerName

  EventSourceMapping:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping'
    Properties:
      BatchSize: 100
      MaximumBatchingWindowInSeconds: 15
      Enabled: true
      EventSourceArn: !Ref EventStreamConsumer
      FunctionName: !GetAtt Function.Arn
      StartingPosition: LATEST
```

When I deploy this template using the SAM CLI, I see errors saying -

```
Unsupported MaximumBatchingWindowInSecond parameter for given event source mapping type. (Service: AWSLambda; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValueException; Request ID: xxxxxxxxxx)
```

Observe the Error message for the parameter name.

Can someone explain why this is occurring and how this can be mitigated?

Answer (score 1):

Batch window, error handling, and concurrency settings are not available for HTTP/2 stream consumers.

To understand completely you can refer the link below.
[Using AWS Lambda with Amazon Kinesis](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg//with-kinesis.html)
What you are trying to do will be supported with HTTP/1 not with HTTP/2.